# Função power retornando valores incorretos dentro do loop while

Tags: c, formatação, scanf

Tenho uma função `power` que retorna o valor de uma potenciação recebendo os parâmetros `n` e `p` (`n^p`). Fora do *loop* `while` a função retorna os valores corretos, porém dentro do *loop* a função retorna valores incorretos, segue abaixo o código:

```
double power(double, int);

int main()
{
    double n;
    int p;

    printf("%.0f\n", power(5, 2)); // aqui retorna o valor correto de 5^2

   while (1)
   {
        printf("Enter n and p (n^p): ");
        scanf("%.0f", &p);
        scanf("%d", &n);

        printf("The pow is: %.0f\n", power(n, p)); // aqui retorna valores incorretos
    }

   return 0;
}

double power(double n, int p)
{
   double pow = 1;
   int i;

for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
    pow *= n;

   return pow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema é a [formatação do `scan()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) errada, e nada tem a ver com o laço. `d` é para inteiros, e o `double` deve usar `lf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double power(double n, int p) {
    double pow = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) pow *= n;
    return pow;
}

int main() {
    printf("%.0f\n", power(5, 2));
    printf("Enter n and p (n^p): ");
    double n;
    int p;
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    scanf("%d", &p);
    printf("The pow is: %.0f\n", power(n, p));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jwnFw5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mukufwxk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Pow.c).